# Can I use it instead of the value of LiveDate when I use observe in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A works well, can I use `it` instead of the value of `LiveData<List<MVoice>>` when I use `observe` in Kotlin, just like Code B

**Code A**

```
val adapter = VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel)
binding.mvoiceList.adapter=adapter
   mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){listMove->
   adapter.submitList(listMove)
}


class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
  fun listVoiceBySort(): LiveData<List<MVoice>> = mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(sortBy.value!!)
}
```

**Code B**

```
val adapter = VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel)
binding.mvoiceList.adapter=adapter
   mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
   adapter.submitList(it)
}


class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
  fun listVoiceBySort(): LiveData<List<MVoice>> = mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(sortBy.value!!)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can use `it` instead of explicit parameter `listMove`